# iPhone : How to call other method from [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void ) { }

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using following code to combine `.mp4` and `.caf` into `.mov`. (Note : I know how to play video so dont give code for that)

```
 AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];  //AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough 

NSString* videoName = @"export.mov";

NSString *exportPath = [document stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
NSLog(@"Export : %@",exportUrl);

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
}

_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;//@"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
NSLog(@"file type %@",_assetExport.outputFileType);
_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
_assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
```

---

```
[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {  
     switch (_assetExport.status) 
     {
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             //   export complete 

             NSLog(@"Export Complete");
       ------>>> // From Here I want play movie using MPMoviePlayerController.<<<--------- 


             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             NSLog(@"Export Failed");
             NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);

             //                export error (see exportSession.error)  
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             NSLog(@"Export Failed");
             NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);

             //                export cancelled  
             break;

     }


 }       

 ];
```

So for playing video I called other method `[self playVideo]` but its not playing.

I am trying to use this approach b'coz `[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {  }` will use other thread to export video.

If I try to call `[self playVideo]` after the above code. It will not get video b'coz the video is still creating under the above method.

I have also tried to notify from the `AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted` but its not playing video.

So my question is How can I play video from that method? Or How can switch control to main thread so I can play video successfully?

Comment: Try change AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough to AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality

Comment: I am not asking for video quality.

Comment: Are you getting your video after exporting? do save it your NSDocumentdirector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playVideo) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```